# What's the meaning of "comp induces a strict total ordering on the equivalence classes determined by equiv"?

Tags: c++

I read [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) and find a note said: `comp induces a strict total ordering on the equivalence classes determined by equiv`, which `comp` is user-provided binaryPredicate and `equiv` is an expression equivalent to `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.

My question is, `comp` and `equiv` have established strict weak ordering, so why they can induce a strict total ordering?